# Adjusted TF-IDF where many terms appear in every document

Tags: r, clustering, natural-language, text-mining, tf-idf

Struggling with something so hoped the brilliant minds of the internet could help me out.

I have a large dataset of job postings from which I have extracted the skill demand (no. of times a skill is requested) for each occupation (which I am treating as documents for TF-IDF). Essentially each row is a different occupation, and each column is a skill, so each cell is the number of times a skill appears in an occupation's job postings

An issue I have is that because of the large number of postings, all of the more general skills, and even some more specialised skills, often appear in every occupation (i.e. document) at least once, making the TF-IDF value 0. This is problematic as though I do I want skills that appear frequently in every occupation weighted down relative to that frequency, as you can imagine these skills are still important to the occupations, and I'm also getting a 0 score for some specialised skills just because they appear infrequently in every occupation.

Have tried adjusting the IDF formula to $idf(t) =1+log \left (\frac{numDocs}{docFreq+1}  \right )$ to set a lower bound, but this doesn't solve everything - is there a better way to do this? I'm thinking it might also be reasonable to treat skills that appear very infrequently in an occupation as outliers and set their frequency to 0 to partially solve this.

Would love to hear anyone else's thoughts on this.

Comment: If you have words that appear in every document, they are meaningless, so you can simply ignore them, as we do with stopwords.

Comment: @Tim They appear in every document, but I'm using TF-IDF to find the relative importance of skills to an occupation, and the frequency that they appear varies a lot between the occupations. One occupation may have 10,000 jobs that request teamwork skills, and another may only have 10 - I would want its TF-IDF score to reflect that, but still adjust to an extent based on frequency across documents.

Comment: If it's in every document it doesn't have any value. It's like “the”.

Comment: @Tim I would agree if I were looking for just "uniqueness", but I'm using IDF here to add some weighting to the TF of skills based off their frequency across occupations. For the purpose of my research it is still significant if e.g. technicians' communication skills TF-IDF score were lower than scientists, but both would be 0 with the original formula for TF-IDF.

If I don't weight enough using IDF though I won't be able to get an accurate picture of how important that skill is relative to other skills within the occupation, so that's the main issue.